# Sending email in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, email, wysiwyg

Hi I was wondering what would be a good way of sending emails through an MVC2 web application?
The purpose is to create a (web)UI for administrators to easily send emails through both in HTML and plain text. My understanding so far is that I should maybe ideally have an EmailController and two views one for the plain text version and one for the HTML one. So both views should be rendered from their corresponding ActionResult in the controller. I know also that I can use the classes of System.Net.Mail

I've briefly looked into the MVCMailer package that you can install with Nuget. It seems great Though I'm not sure how well it works with MVC2. I have some milestones on this project and one further a head is to also implement some kind of wysiwyg-editor for the one composing the email as their HTML knowledge are very basic.

Anyone got any good suggestions on how to go about with this?

Comment: What is the question?  Do you want to know how to send email using System.Net.Mail?  Do you want to know what the best WYSIWYG editor for emails?  This needs clarification.

Comment: Pretty sure MVCMailer uses Razor so that alone would make it difficult to use in MVC2.

Comment: @threalmitchconnors: Yes you are right. The question is about the mailing.

Answer (score 0):

You could start simple and build from there.  Maybe provide one action in your email controller that simply takes in inputs (From, Subject, Message, etc. - I would put this in a view model) from your administrator.  Provide a radio button that gives them the option to select HTML or Plain text.  In your code, depending on what they choose, you can tell System.Net.Mail what format to send the email in.

Also, if the administrator simply wants to write text, you could design a simple HTML layout that poses as an HTML email template that can provide the flair surrounding the text entered.

There are many options, hopefully this helped a little.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of solutions here : http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=email

Comment: 404 : Page Not Found

You might be here because:

The page you are looking for does not exist anymore.

Comment: @user1855153 a down vote, really? A simple note that Nuget.org changed their search URL would have gone much farther in maintaining a great community of answers.

Comment: a search link really? I farmed some votes just to downvote your answer. The page not found was just a bonus and I'd downvote you twice if I could.